# Github merge issue

Tags: git

Im trying to merge a feature branch and using a command line merge as recommendeb by Github -

On the PR requests, I see this -

Step 1: From your project repository, check out a new branch and test the changes.

```
git checkout -b tom-feature/handle-empty-return-from-service devel
git pull git@github.com:TOM2000/cloud-detection.git tom-feature/handle-empty-return-from-service
```

The first command works fine but the pull command gives me merge conflict. Why should I get a merge conflict when Im trying to pull from the branch and not trying to merge it.

Comment: Do you see a merge conflict on PR?

Comment: You are trying to merge if you and someone else both committed to that branch.

Answer (score 0):

`pull` means "fetch the changes from the remote and merge them into my current branch" (roughly and by default).  The "merge them into my current branch" part can conflict, just like any merge.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to *fetch* the changes *without merging*, you should use `git fetch` instead.

As @Mark mentioned, what `git pull` does is `git fetch` + `git merge`. Since `git pull` tries to merge the newly downloaded data to your current working files, it is *normal* to get a merge conflict.

Read more about `git fetch` vs `git pull` [here](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/difference-between-git-fetch-git-pull).